# OutputCache VaryByParam not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, outputcache

I'm working on an old project where we are introducing output caching to certain parts of the site. I have the following declaration at the top of the page:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="q" %>
```

This works perfectly where the URL contains a value for `q` in the query string. However, I'd also expect that when `q` is `null` that it would cache a result for this. However, this isn't what's happening so I'm just wondering if there's anything I can do to get my expected behaviour?

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask should be cached as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?q=4

Comment: @naathon Where does it say that? Struggling to find it :(

Comment: @naathon You've misunderstood the question. My `VaryByParam` is `q` but when the value of `q` is `null` the result isn't cached